# How to Install Apache Ambari on MacOS?

Tags: macos, installation, ambari

Is there any other alternative procedure of installing either from source as described in below link?

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.5.2

or

installing HDP version of Ambari.

Do I have any other alternative source to easy install Ambari eg., like from binary files?

Answer (score 0):

You can build and run Apache Ambari on OSX from source (via the doc link you provided).

There are no binary files that are pre-built and offered by Ambari for OSX.

Even if you get Ambari up and running on OSX you will **NOT** be able to provision an HDP stack on OSX. This is because the services defined by the HDP stack only support linux or windows. Yum, a package manager utility, is required to install the services (ie. Yarn, Spark, etc.) on linux. Yum is not available on osx.

You would have to write a custom stack for it to work on osx. That would be a good deal of work.

That being said there is nothing stopping you from installing services via source or pre-packaged bins from the various apache repos on OSX. This will allow you to run Hadoop processes locally on OSX but without the niceties provided by Ambari for provisioning, managing, and monitoring.